# Translation of Graphics object doesn't affect WM_PRINT call

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, sendmessage

I'm currently using a WM_PRINT call to render a control into a graphics object:

```
GraphicsState backup = graphics.Save();
graphics.TranslateTransform(50, 50);

IntPtr destHdc = graphics.GetHdc();

const int flags = (int)(DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN | DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT | DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT);
NativeMethods.SendMessage(srcControl.Handle, (Int32)WM.WM_PRINT, (IntPtr)destHdc, (IntPtr)flags);
graphics.ReleaseHdc(destHdc);
graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, new Point(), new Point(srcControl.Width, srcControl.Height));

graphics.Restore(backup);
```

I need to use the WM_PRINT command rather than control.DrawToBitmap() as the DrawToBitmap method does not handle controls which are off screen.

The code will correctly transform the drawing of the blue line by 50,50, but the control is rendered in the top left corner (0,0). Is there any way I can use the WM_PRINT command to print into a specific location (50,50)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the `WM_PRINT` uses the `Device context` and not via the `graphics`, so the `translate transform` is not affected. It's affected only with the drawing methods called on the `graphics`.
Here is a workaround:

```
GraphicsState backup = graphics.Save();
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(srcControl.Width, srcControl.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
IntPtr destHdc = g.GetHdc();

const int flags = (int)(DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN | DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT |     DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT);
NativeMethods.SendMessage(srcControl.Handle, (Int32)WM.WM_PRINT, destHdc,  (IntPtr)flags);
g.ReleaseHdc(destHdc);
graphics.DrawImage(bm, new Point(50,50));
graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, new Point(), new Point(srcControl.Width, srcControl.Height));

graphics.Restore(backup);
```